# The items of dropdown menu overflow from the box

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, semantic-ui

[image]
Using ReactJs and SemanticUI. I tried to apply different CSS properties (overflow hidden, position absolute, fixed/static, width) on Dropdown, .dropdown-content, .dropdown-container, no success

```
<div className="dropdown-container">
<Dropdown
         icon="ui search icon"
         id="roles"
         type="text"
         options={[
         {
         key: t("flot.split.roles.principal"),
         text: t("flot.split.roles.principal"),
         value: t("flot.split.roles.principal")
         },
         {
         key: t("flot.split.roles.songwriter"),
         text: t("flot.split.roles.songwriter"),
         value: t("flot.split.roles.songwriter")
         },
         {
         key: t("flot.split.roles.producer"),
         text: t("flot.split.roles.producer"),
         value: t("flot.split.roles.producer")
         },
         {
         key: t("flot.split.roles.singer"),
         text: t("flot.split.roles.singer"),
         value: t("flot.split.roles.singer")
         },
         ]}
         placeholder={t("collaborateur.attribut.indication.role")}
         search
         multiple={true}
         selection
         fluid
         value={currentRoleValue}
         onChange={this.roleChange}
         />
   </div>
   <div className="sous-titre">                           {t("collaborateur.attribut.indication.role2")}
  </div>
  </div>
```

```
.dropdown-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: "460px";
}
.Dropdown {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply additional styles, you can do so via css. Make your css file, then import it.

```
import './path/to/css.css';
```

Make sure to give your element a className.

```
<Dropdown
         icon="ui search icon"
         id="roles"
         type="text"
         className="myDropdown" />
```

Then in your css file reference your element with its class name.

```
.myDropdown {
  // css here....
}
```

Comment: You applied a className to your <Dropdown className="myOriginalName" /> component? Also, I always try to make up my own original names for to avoid any conflicts.